# WCF - spawn a new worker thread and return to caller without waiting for it to finnish

Tags: multithreading, wcf

I have a WCF web service hosted in IIS- This service has a method - lets call it DoSomething(). DoSomething() is called from a client-side application.

DoSomething performs some work and returns the answer to the user. Now I need to log how often DoSomething is being called. I can add it to the DoSomething function so that it will for every call write to an sql database and update a counter, but this will slow down the DoSomething method as the user needs to wait for this extra database call.

Is it a good option to let the DoSomething method spawn a new thread which will update the counter in the database, and then just return the answer from the DoSomething method to the user without waiting for the thread to finnish? Then I will not know if the database update fails, but that is not critical.

Any problems with spawning a new background thread and not wait for it to finnish in WCF? Or is there a better way to solve this?

**Update:** To ask the question in a little different way. Is it a bad idea to spawn new threads insde a wcf web service method?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is one of reliability. Is this a call you care about? If the IIS process crashes after you returned the response, but before your thread completes, does it matter? If no, then you can use client side C# tools. If it *does* matter, then you must use a reliable queuing technology.

If you use the client side then spawning a new thread *just to block on a DB call* is never the correct answer. What you want is to make the call async, and for that you use [SqlCommand.BeginExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery.aspx) after you ensure that [`AsyncronousProcessing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.asynchronousprocessing.aspx) is enabled on the connection.

If you need *reliable* processing then you can use a pattern like [Asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) which relies on persisted queues.

As a side note things like logging, or hit counts, and the like are a huge performance bottleneck if done in the naive approach of writing to the database on every single HTTP request. You must batch and flush.

Comment: What I am trying to do here is to do things like logging and hit counts without affecting the performance of the web service - and as such your side note is very interesting. Can you share some more details on how to do this in a good way?

Comment: Instead of logging every call, cache in memory and update the database only every 10 seconds for example. This can cause, in case of crash, a loss of 10 seconds of logging, but the benefits usually outweigh this problem. Instead of updating a counter +1,+1,+1,+1 you update it once with +4. Instead of logging 'here', then 'there', then 'everywhere' you log in one call 'here, there, everywhere'. The gist of it is to reduce the number of round trips to the database and, most importantly, aggregate those hit counter +1, +1, +1 updates.

Comment: To understand why those +1,+1,+1 hit counters are so damaging consider that they often update the *same* record and and as such they block each other, as only one transaction can update a record at any time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only track a single method like `DoSomething()` in service then you can create an custom operation behavior and apply it over the method.

The operation behavior will contain the code that logs the info to database. In that operation behavior you can use the .NET 4.0's new TPL library to create a task that will take care of database logging. If you use TPL you don't need to worry about directly creating threads.

The advantage of using operation behvaior tomorrow you need to track another method then at that time instead of duplicating the code there you are just going to mark the method with the custom operation behavior. If you want to track all the methods then you should go for service behavior.

To know more about operation behaviors check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.aspx

To know more about TPL(Task Parallel Library) check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: Thank you for a good answer. I can probably use operation behavior (I need to study it a little), but if I for some reason can't use it - do you see any problems with spawning a new thread directly within the DoSomething method?

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.0 or older version?

Comment: I am not using .Net 4.0 at the moment, but it could be an option to upgrade.